# Is there a way to omit Active Record casting (from postgres ranges)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a method that checks the date intersections for my model instance.

```
def intersections
  Reservation.where("daterange && ?", self.daterange)
end
```

Suppose I have the reservation `r = Reservation.last`

`=> #<Reservation id: 3, home_id: 1, daterange: Sun, 10 Feb 2020...Fri, 21 Feb 2020>`

`r.intersections`

Excepted query:

`SELECT "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE (daterange && '[2020-02-10,2020-02-21)')`

Actual query:

`SELECT "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE (daterange && '2020-02-10','2020-02-11','2020-02-12','2020-02-13','2020-02-14','2020-02-15','2020-02-16','2020-02-17','2020-02-18','2020-02-19','2020-02-20')`

**schema:**

```
create_table "reservations", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.daterange "daterange"
end
```

I tried a lot of variations but it seems that the casting is hidden somewhere deep inside Active Record. Can I just turn it off for this query?

Comment: @max AR puts quotes in the query, so it fails. However AR::Attributes work just fine. I added `attribute :daterange, range: true` to the model according to [guide](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html). Thanks! Сan you add this answer, I will mark it accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Attributes API to setup casting.

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :daterange, range: true

  def intersections
    Reservation.where(
      "daterange && ?", self.daterange
    )
  end
end
```

```
irb(main):026:0> Reservation.first.intersections
  Reservation Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "reservations".* FROM "reservations" ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Reservation Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE (daterange && '[2020-02-14,2020-02-16)') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Reservation id: 1, daterange: "[2020-02-14,2020-02-16)", created_at: "2020-02-14 11:13:13", updated_at: "2020-02-14 11:13:13">, #<Reservation id: 2, daterange: "(,)", created_at: "2020-02-14 11:33:16", updated_at: "2020-02-14 11:33:16">]>
```